# Django and Postgresql with DateTimeField model field giving different results

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, timezone

I have defined a class for which I inherit form:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In postgresql I see the entry created like:

```
2014-02-24 17:04:05.904248-05 (correct timezone)
```

And django spits it out like:

```
2014-02-24 22:04:05.904213+00:00 (incorrect)
```

In my settings.py I have,

```
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'
USE_TZ = True
```

I've also noticed a similar issue for the field date_done in djcelery's taskmeta table.

I've done some reading and I know it's quite tricky, just thought if anyone could help.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/timezones/#code  try to install pytz according to document, because it seems Django still think datetime from database is in UTC

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have pytz installed. So I'm at a loss at this point. When I tried to localized with strftime, I got an error saying something to the effect that the timezone is already present.